# Why can't we declare fields as public inside main method in Java?

Tags: java

I am just trying to declare fields inside main method in Java class with different access specifiers.. But I am not able declare fields with access specifier as public, any reason for this ?

Comment: First of all think -- why would you want to do this, what would you achieve? Since you know that variables local to a method are visible only within that same method, even if you could name the `public` or such, what affect would it have on the variable and your program? Answer: none whatsoever, so Java doesn't let you do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare access specifiers for local variables, because the lifetime of those variables is local, e.g. for the main method, any variables declared inside are only accessible inside the main method. Check out this resource from tutorialspoint on local variables:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm

Answer (score 1):

the access specifiers are for `fields` of the `class`. You use the access specifier to define how this fields can be accessed from outside. But the variables declared in the methods are `local variables`. These local variables can not be accessed outside this method blocks. So there is no reason to use access specifiers for them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a public element inside a method. This element exists while the method is executing and cannot be accessed outside this main method.

Answer (score 1):

Fields within a method are local to the method and are therefore don't have access modifiers.

Access modifiers are applied at the class level i.e.

```
public class Person {

  private String name

  public String getName() {
    return this.name
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Local variable can not be public.
public, private, proctacted are only used with class level members.

Assume that if it is possible to do so then also how can you access it out of the method or class.
So specifing scope before locel members is dose not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared in methods (aka local variables) are only accessible within the method. After the method returns, all local variables in the method became unaccessible. You can treat all the local variables as if they were `private`.

Why is it so then?

Local variables' purpose is to temporarily store data during the execution of a method. As we all know, a method either *does* something, or *return* something, or both. While a method is doing this business, objects might be created to help with whatever the method is doing. And the objects are stored in variables. Since these variables only help the method do its job, they are not needed after the method finishes its job (returns).

See? They are temporary. There is no point accessing them from another scope.